# MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database is in suspect mode

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have an database on MS SQL Server 2008 R2, which is currently showing `principle, Disconnected / suspect`.

I have tried, to set DB in emergency mode but got failed and showing message database is in mirroring session.

Anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the situation, & it was not easy to get fix the suspect mode in the Running server.

In my case it happened due to corruption, you can run the DBCC CHECKDB command to check the main reason for the corruption.
If the system tables are corrupt then it's restored from backup. To run this command leave the emergency mode and put the database online.

Also you can follow this, It helped me in that scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947132/mssql-2016-need-to-move-back-to-suspect-mode

Good Day.